# Fusion Tables: Unable to complete import

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've been using Fusion Tables for about a year off and on. Today on attempting to upload a 156kb file, it comes up with 'Unable to complete import'.

I tried reducing the size, then realised most of the other files i'd uploaded were larger, so out of curiosity attempted to upload a previously uploaded file (already stored as a fusion table).
This also fails. I've tried uploading on another account and this also fails with the same message.

Is there anyway to check to see if there is an issue with Fusion Tables? I've read previous questions and those unrelated to size mention an issue with Fusion Tables, or alternatively if there is a way of getting better error reporting from the attempted upload?

Comment: probably something wrong with one of your field names

Comment: As I mentioned files that previously imported do not any more. The files haven't changed. To be thorough though I've checked the fusion tables that exist and they have the same names, so there is no issue with the field names. I hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: Nothing has changed (including no reboots since yesterday), but I am now (with the same files) able to upload, however the data cuts off at 100 rows. There are no error messages and data is well within size limits (and I've attempted to upload previously successful uploads) with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by Google. No changes were made/no reboots today, but fusion tables are working again.